# Delete cookies & cache from internal web browser of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, browser-cache

When using *Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers* edition of Eclipse Juno SR2, and running a web app in the internal web browser, how does one delete that browser’s cookies and cache?

I've searched Eclipse's Help, the Google, and StackOverflow.com, but surprisingly found no direct correct answer to this simple question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse does not really have an Internal Browser. It just uses the default browser on the system. You can change this behaviour from

`Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser`

Clearing cookies should be done from the browser.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Trimming the history list in Eclipse's internal web browser**

I use the internal web browser quite a bit when I'm developing - if nothing else, it's a handy place to test out the GET requests for RESTful web services. I also use Eclipse for HTML writing, and again the internal browser is a useful first test of "does this look right yet?". This means I build up quite a long history list, and the most recent entries – the ones I'm mostly likely to be looking for – require scrolling to find and re-use them. I have not, to date, found a setting inside Eclipse (I'm using 3.3.2 at the time of writing this) to edit the internal browser history. I'd be delighted to be proved wrong.

In the meantime, the workaround is to close Eclipse, then edit the file `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.browser.prefs` where `$WORKSPACE` is your Eclipse workspace root directory. This is a plain text file: my preferred text editor on Linux and Windows is SciTE but it doesn't actually matter which one. This file has a preference key internalWebBrowserHistory, with the format:

`internalWebBrowserHistory=url|*|url|*| ...`

Removing stale entries is straightforward; modifying or adding new entries is perfectly doable, noting that colon characters (:) are escaped with a preceding backslash (\:). Save changes, restart Eclipse, done. Hopefully there will be an internal preference editor to make this easier inside Eclipse in future (or, someone will point out to me that I've been unobservant and that it's already there).